# Opposite of switchMap operator in RxJava2

Tags: rx-java2

I have configuration `Observable` to which I'm subscribing and launching my own `Observable` but I'm having a problem with canceling the running `Observable` upon receiving configuration update.

I was thinking of something like `switchMap` operator but in reverse so when there's a new value from a source `Observable` we're unsubscribing from the mapped `Observable` and subscribing to a new one.

Like this:

```
configuration.
    reverseSwitchMap {
        createMyObservable(it.somethingFromConfiguration) // this observable get's recreated for each configuration update
    }.subscribe {
        // here I'm receiving values from myObservable
    }
```

Is there an operator which could help me solve this problem?

Comment: You **are** describing `switchMap`. What is your inner Observable you are having trouble cancelling?

Comment: I thought switchMap is unsubscribing from the source observable? I do not want this behaviour. I want to still receive updates from configuration observable but when I receive the new value I want to cancel the observable from `createMyObservable` method and create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what switchMap is for.

This should work:

```
fun startUpdates() {
    configuration.toObservable()
        .switchMap { configuration -> MyObservable(configuration) }                  
        .subscribe { //do something }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know. @akarnokd already answered this question in the comments but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm overcomplicating this so for now the solution I created is this:

```
private val disposable: Disposable? = null

fun startUpdates() {
    configuration.toObservable()
        .forEach { configuration ->
            disposable?.dispose
            disposable = MyObservable(configuration)
                .subscribe { //do something }
        }
}
```

It suffices for now, though I'll leave the question open in case someone finds a better solution.

Comment: This is what `switchMap` is for.

Comment: I just checked and you're right. I'm dumb I guess. My understanding of this operator was always flawed it seems. Add an answer and I'll accept it.